# ESLINT: Passing numeric values to the rules in the config file?

Tags: jshint, eslint

Just started to configure the aslant config file (.eslintrc) and I found a few examples and it seems they are passing numeric values to the rules but I am unable to confirm what these values mean. For example

```
  "rules": {
    "no-alert": 2,
    "wrap-regex": 0
```

What does the 2 signify? What does the 0? Is there a 1?

The docs don't seem to outline this. I am a little confused on how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 0 : disabled
- 1 : warning
- 2 : error

As specified in the [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuring-rules) :)